# PYSNMP: How to change from a GetNext Request to a Get Request efficiently

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I use pysnmp 4.3.1, Using [Packet Level SNMP](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/contents.html#packet-level-snmp) syntax.
I am try to look for an efficient way of changing to a Get Request after a GetNext Request.
For example I need to walk on this whole branch(1.3.6.1.2.1.11) and afterwards I need to get these 2 oids(1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0, 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0).
I also need to do these requests on SNMPv1 and without any varbinds.
This is my code:

```
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dispatch import AsyncoreDispatcher
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram import udp
from pyasn1.codec.ber import encoder, decoder
from pysnmp.proto import api
from time import time

# Protocol version to use
pMod = api.protoModules[api.protoVersion1]
#pMod = api.protoModules[api.protoVersion2c]

# SNMP table header
headVars = [ pMod.ObjectIdentifier((1,3,6,1,2,1,11)) ]
next1 = '1.3.6.1.2.1.11'
get2 = '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0'

# Build PDU
reqPDU =  pMod.GetNextRequestPDU()
pMod.apiPDU.setDefaults(reqPDU)
pMod.apiPDU.setVarBinds(reqPDU, [ (x, pMod.null) for x in headVars ])

# Build message
reqMsg = pMod.Message()
pMod.apiMessage.setDefaults(reqMsg)
pMod.apiMessage.setCommunity(reqMsg, 'public')
pMod.apiMessage.setPDU(reqMsg, reqPDU)

startedAt = time()

def cbTimerFun(timeNow):
    if timeNow - startedAt > 3:
        raise Exception("Request timed out")

def cbRecvFun(transportDispatcher, transportDomain, transportAddress,
              wholeMsg, reqPDU=reqPDU, headVars=headVars):
    while wholeMsg:
        rspMsg, wholeMsg = decoder.decode(wholeMsg, asn1Spec=pMod.Message())
        rspPDU = pMod.apiMessage.getPDU(rspMsg)
        # Match response to request
        if pMod.apiPDU.getRequestID(reqPDU)==pMod.apiPDU.getRequestID(rspPDU):
            # Check for SNMP errors reported
            errorStatus = pMod.apiPDU.getErrorStatus(rspPDU)
            if errorStatus and errorStatus != 2:
                raise Exception(errorStatus)
            # Format var-binds table
            varBindTable = pMod.apiPDU.getVarBindTable(reqPDU, rspPDU)
            # Report SNMP table
            for tableRow in varBindTable:
                for name, val in tableRow:
                    print('from: %s, %s = %s' % (
                        transportAddress, name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()
                        )
                    )

            # Generate request for next row
            if(next1 in name.prettyPrint()):
                pMod.apiPDU.setVarBinds(
                    reqPDU, [ (x, pMod.null) for x,y in varBindTable[-1] ]
                    )
                pMod.apiPDU.setRequestID(reqPDU, pMod.getNextRequestID())
                transportDispatcher.sendMessage(
                    encoder.encode(reqMsg), transportDomain, transportAddress
                    )
            else:
                reqPDU = pMod.GetRequestPDU()
                pMod.apiPDU.setVarBinds(
                    reqPDU, [ (get2, pMod.null) ]
                    )
                pMod.apiPDU.setRequestID(reqPDU, pMod.getNextRequestID())
                transportDispatcher.sendMessage(
                    encoder.encode(reqMsg), transportDomain, transportAddress
                    )
            global startedAt
            if time() - startedAt > 3:
                raise Exception('Request timed out')
            startedAt = time()
    return wholeMsg

transportDispatcher = AsyncoreDispatcher()

transportDispatcher.registerRecvCbFun(cbRecvFun)
transportDispatcher.registerTimerCbFun(cbTimerFun)

transportDispatcher.registerTransport(
    udp.domainName, udp.UdpSocketTransport().openClientMode()
)
transportDispatcher.sendMessage(
    encoder.encode(reqMsg), udp.domainName, ('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)
)
transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)

transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()

transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
```

This code is taken mostly from this [GetNext](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/v1arch/asyncore/manager/cmdgen/walking-operations.html#walk-agent-mib-snmpv1) example.
How can I change from a sequence of GetNext Requests to a sequence of many Get Requests, while using SNMPv1 and no varbinds?

Comment: Do those GET and GETNEXT queries relate to each other anyhow? If not, could you just put your GET code in a branch that runs when you run out of your GETNEXT OIDs and would just drop out of GETNEXT iteration otherwise? Do you really need switching over from GET to GETNEXT? Note that GETNEXT 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1 is equivalent to GET 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 .

Comment: Those were just examples, and for the record 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 is not on this branch 1.3.6.1.2.1.11. You mixed up between the 11 in the branch with two ones. Sometimes my Get OIDs are not located in my branches

Comment: I assume  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 is the OID you want to GET once you are done GETNEXT'ing 1.3.6.1.2.1.11 . What do you mean 'with no varbinds'?

Comment: By 'with no varbinds' I mean: Without sending multiple OIDs in one request. I found that old SNMP devices don't respond well to those type of requests and sometimes don't respond at all.

Comment: Was I unclear with the question? If so can you ask me what you want and I will answer.